# Indexing in search engine rewrited urls /?id=something --> /something_something/

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have rewrited the urls of my website, example:

```
/?id=1 --> /page1/
/?id=2 --> /page2/
/?id=3 --> /page3/
```

Now, how can I index / make search engine appear `/page1/` ?
In the website I am still using the url with the `id`

```
<a href="/?id=1">visit page 1</a>
```

Should I rename all the old URLs my website with the new ones?
If it's yes, how can I do that fastly? I have hundred of URLs with the `id`

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: @PanamaJack which? the rewrite is in the .htaccess file

Comment: That's not what I meant. I know it's in .htaccess. You need to provide your code in the question if you want someone to help you.

Comment: Just search and replace ?id= with page and done :)